# Could not retrieve the required installation files

Tags: system-installation

I get this message when I'm trying to install ubuntu from the start up help. Just rebooting and starting from the cd didn't work for me.

I'm refered to a log for this problem and I find the errors, but I have no idea what it all means:

```
01-08 18:29 ERROR  CommonBackend: The md5 of the metalink does match
01-08 18:29 ERROR  CommonBackend: Cannot authenticate the metalink file, it might be corrupt
None
01-08 18:29 DEBUG  TaskList: #### Finished get_metalink
01-08 18:29 DEBUG  TaskList: New task get_file_md5
01-08 18:29 DEBUG  TaskList: #### Running get_file_md5...
01-08 18:30 DEBUG  TaskList: #### Finished get_file_md5
01-08 18:30 ERROR  CommonBackend: Invalid md5 for ISO C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso (dccff28314d9ae4ed262cfc6f35e5153 != 119cb63b48c9a18f31f417f09655efbd)
None
01-08 18:30 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished check_iso
01-08 18:30 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Finished use_cd
01-08 18:30 DEBUG  TaskList: ## Running extract_kernel...
01-08 18:30 ERROR  TaskList: Could not retrieve the required installation files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 618, in extract_kernel
Exception: Could not retrieve the required installation files
01-08 18:30 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
01-08 18:30 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist
01-08 18:30 ERROR  root: Could not retrieve the required installation files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 58, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 130, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 205, in run_cd_menu
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 122, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 228, in run_cd_boot
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 618, in extract_kernel
Exception: Could not retrieve the required installation files
```

Anyone who can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
01-08 18:30 ERROR  CommonBackend: Invalid md5 for ISO C:\ubuntu\install\installation.iso (dccff28314d9ae4ed262cfc6f35e5153 != 119cb63b48c9a18f31f417f09655efbd)
None
```

The line above suggests that the ISO image you're using is corrupted. Try downloading it again.